# Bad texture color and alignment in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I'm currently coding a little game in OpenGL and C.

I'm trying to create textures. I coded a function to open RAW files and tried to create a *skybox* around my scene. I achieved doing this by creating 6 planes and applying on each of them one bitmap file.

However, I have some problems :

1. we can see, in my *first person* view, problems at every edge of my cube even if it seems that I have good coordinates;
2. in my *objective came* view which is far from origin, we can see a hole in my edges;
3. colors don't correspond between original picture and texture.

## General situation

My cube is created in the function `void display (void)` with the code below :

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_negx);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-50,-50,0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(-50,+50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-50,+50,0);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_negy);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(-50,-50);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(-50,50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(50,50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(50,-50);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_negz);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(+50,-50,0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(+50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(-50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-50,-50,0);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_posx);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(+50,+50,0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(+50,+50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(+50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(+50,-50,0);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_posy);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-50,+50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(+50,-50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(+50,+50,+50);
glEnd();


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_posz);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-50,+50,0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-50,+50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(+50,+50,+50);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(+50,+50,0);
glEnd();
```

I declared my texture identifiers as global variables with

```
GLuint texture_negx, texture_negy, texture_negz, texture_posx, texture_posy, texture_posz;
```

My textures are created in my `void init (void)` function with :

```
texture_negx = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/negx.BMP", 0);
texture_negy = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/negy.BMP", 0);
texture_negz = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/negz.BMP", 0);
texture_posx = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/posx.BMP", 0);
texture_posy = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/posy.BMP", 0);
texture_posz = LoadTextureRAW("/Users/Jean/Downloads/posz.BMP", 0);
```

My function to read RAW files is :

```
GLuint LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int wrap )
{
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;

    // open texture data
    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

    // allocate buffer
    width = 2048;
    height = 2048;
    data = malloc( width * height * 3 );

    // read texture data
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    // allocate a texture name
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    // select our current texture
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    // select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    // if wrap is true, the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
    //       ... false, the texture ends at the edges (clamp)
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );

    // build our texture mipmaps
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,
                  GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

    // free buffer
    free(data);

    return texture;
}
```

## Visible edges of the cube

As you can see in [this link](http://postimg.org/image/f29oiv151/), two visible holes appear in the left and right part of the picture when in my first person view.

I think this problem is related to the other one that I get when I use my subjective camera view, that you can see [here](http://postimg.org/image/70qgajzfd/).

**I'm sure that this problem doesn't come from texture itself because I tried to make my cube with white sides and the problem was still here.**

## Strange colors

I also have a problem with the color of my texture, which should actually be *natural*.
I thought that it was because I use bitmap files instead of .RAW files and that the fact that my function which opens files doesn't care about header. But I tried to delete first bytes in my BMP file and it just made a part of the texture disappear.
I noticed at this moment that there is a texture again under the first one :o ! Maybe someone can also explain me this.

This problem is less important for me than the two others but I would be happy to solve it anyway.

## Conclusion

Thank you if you've read until here! I really can't figure 
out these problems and any help is more than welcome :)

Sorry that pictures are not embedded in my post but I haven't enough *reputation* on Stack Overflow to do this.

If you have any question or if I can help you by giving any other piece of code, let me know!

Thank you very much in advance to everyone who will answer this post! :)

Comment: As for the colors: looks to me like your image data is in BGR format, so R and B are swapped. You could fix this by using `GL_BGR` instead of `GL_RGB` when specifying the texture data.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for colors. But I still have this strange problem of gold in my texture :(